# OnePlus6 oxygen os 10.3.0 "popup notifications no longer available on your version of Android"

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, android-versions, oxygenos, oneplus-6

I updated my OnePlus 6 to oxygen os 10.3.0, and I can't enable pop notifications, especially on whatsapp.
Attached are the screen shots.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

(Click to enlarge)

Comment: Looks like this is [a known "issue"/limitation on Android 10](https://forums.androidcentral.com/android-10/976009-pop-up-notifications-not-working-pixel-3-xl-after-update-android-10-a.html).

Comment: [switch off adaptive notifications](https://community.o2.co.uk/t5/Android/Android-10-Popup-notifications-S10-Whatsapp/td-p/1287258). If that doesn't help, try enabling lockscreen notifications

Comment: It's a [known bug](https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/whatsapp-pop-up-notifications-banking-app-not-working.1123486/). See if whatsapp and other affected apps , battery optimization is set to off. Also disable in advanced settings of battery optimization, anything like deep optimization . Best is to disable all advanced battery optimization options